# unable to install Homebrew on macOS Sonoma Version 14.2.1

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, macos-sonoma

I was trying to install Homebrew in my MacOS Sonoma Version 14.2.1 .
I went to [brew.sh](https://brew.sh) .
I found this command.

```
 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

But, this command thrown error:

```
curl: 28 failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75029 ms: couldn't connect to server
```

Then I searched on internet, and Found Some Solutions.

1. Try changing Network Service Provider.

*By the way I am from India and Using "JIO Network Service Provider"*
So I changed it, it didn't worked.

2. check if https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh is accessible in browser or not.

I tried this, but the URL was not reachable.

If anybody can help me in installing Homebrew, It will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you go to raw.githubusercontent.com in your browser?

Comment: Not sure why your question was voted down. Seems ok to me. I also can't install brew.

Answer (score -2):

go to wifi > details and select dns from the sidebar and paste this ipv6 address 2001:4860:4860::8888
pretty sure this will resolve your problem......